# R Markdown producing error: Input must be a vector, not an environment?

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have to update some reports I created a while ago using Markdown and when I even try to just create a title page I get an error. Running the code below

````
---
title: "Report"
author: "Author"
date: "12/16/2022"
output: word_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```
````

produces this error message:

processing file: Testing.Rmd
Error in `stop_vctrs()`:
! Input must be a vector, not an environment.
Backtrace:

1. rmarkdown::render(...)
2. vctrs:::stop_scalar_type(`<fn>`(`<env>`), "")
3. vctrs:::stop_vctrs(msg, "vctrs_error_scalar_type", actual = x)
   Execution halted

Any idea what's going on? Been searching online for an hour and can't find anything

Comment: The ending \`\`\` should be on a new line. Once I did that, it worked for me.

Comment: I have the ``` as a new line in my code in R Studio, I just couldn't write it that way here

Comment: Interesting, whenI did that in my RStudio, it produced a word file (R v4.2.2).

Comment: Already tried after restarting R and w/o loading add. packages?

Comment: I just ended up completely uninstalling R and RStudio, after reinstalling it's working again